# Could Not Find "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime"

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to run my UWP project. However, whenever I attempt to build it I get an error:

> Could not find SDK "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime, Version=1.0

This happens whether I open a previously-created project or create a brand new one. I'm on Windows 10 build 14393 and am using the 14393 SDK. I've hunted through the `.appxmanifest`, `.csproj` and `project.json` files, but I can't find any reference whatsoever to this `Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime` package. Has anyone else run into this or been able to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check the `Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime` folder and the inside contents under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\`:

[image]
If the folder is missing or it's empty inside, you are missing a part of your SDK.

The fastest solution is to copy it from other machine, on which the problem doesn't exists. If you don't have access to other machine, repairing or reinstalling the Visual Studio will fix the problem.